# List of Source Control Systems with Visual Studio Plugins

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, version-control

Is there a list of all the source control systems that have visual studio plugins?  If not, we can make one here...

Comment: I think most of the Source control have got Visual Studio plugin

Comment: links to the plugins might be useful....

Comment: Top answer on google for "visual studio source control" - Bill the Lizard says its "not constructive", 6463 people disagree...wtg SO!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/)

- [AnkhSVN](http://AnkhSVN.Open.Collab.Net/)
- [VisualSVN](http://VisualSVN.Com/)

### [Git](http://git-scm.com/)

- [Git Extensions](http://GitExtensions.SourceForge.Net/)
- [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/)

### Team Foundation Server

### Visual Source Safe

### CVS

### IBM Rational ClearCase

### [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/features/third-party-integrations/visual-studio-integration.aspx)

### Mercurial

- [VisualHG](http://VisualHg.CodePlex.Com/)

Comment: +1 for VisualSVN. It's really nice

Comment: Thanks. The list is very helpful:) And let me add two more version control tools which work perfectly for me: 1.SourceAnywhere Standalone; 2.SourceAnywhere Hosted.

Answer (score 2):

Visual SVN with Tortoise and ankhsvn plugin works like a charm. Very easy to install and administrate.

Answer (score 1):

There's also Git Source Control Provider for Visual Studio:

http://gitscc.codeplex.com/

This one actually works with VS2010 for me. Git Extensions does not.

Answer (score 1):

[AccuRev's Microsoft Visual Studio Plug-in](http://www.accurev.com/accubridge-visual-studio.html)

Answer (score 0):

Team Foundation Server

Answer (score 0):

IBM Rational ClearCase

Answer (score 0):

SourceGear's Vault has a Visual Studio plugin. Some of Vault's great features are:

- free for single users
- SQL Server backend
- atomic checkins / changesets

[Screenshots of Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/screenshots.html)

Comment: I've been using SG Vault for 6 years now. It's terrible. I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

### [IBM Rational Team Concert](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/3.0.1?p=news#vstudio)

This client integration supports Jazz Source Control, Work Items and Build Engine.

Answer (score -2):

Visual SourceSafe

Comment: Visual Source UNsafe would be more appropriate.....