# Single Web Application pointing to multiple localhost on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, web-applications

I am working on a web application which has 2 types of users: provider and consumer. Almost everything is same on both except a few rules.
I have hosted the same application to 2 different addresses like `http://localhost/consumer` and `http://localhost/provider` (working well till now).
Now I have a situation. If I make any changes to the rules of provider, I want only `http://localhost/provider` to reflect that and not the consumer. Same for the consumer. Is it possible from visual studio? Please suggest.

Comment: What does _" changes to the provider"_ mean?

Comment: @CodeCaster 'changes to the rules of provider'

Comment: Right. I mean what does that change entail? A code change? Then you can either detect what URL is being requested and base your logic in code on that, or simply deploy two variants of the same application.

Comment: Yes. Its code changes. Actually I am using the same 2 variants of same application right now. I just wanted to know if its possible to work the same on a single one. That would make my work much simple and will help in integration too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use source control systems like visual studio team foundation server for it and make separate branch for consumer and provider. for more details about Team foundation server and branching you can refer following links

[Team Foundation Server Fundamentals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364062(v=vs.80).aspx)

[Branching and Merging Guidance for Team Foundation Server](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Branching-and-Merging-Guidance-for-Team-Foundation-Server)

You can find a fairly comprehensive list of other alternative for source control at this thread

[List of Source Control Systems with Visual Studio Plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653379/list-of-source-control-systems-with-visual-studio-plugins)